# How do I map buttons for libwacom

Tags: udev, wacom

I would like to add a wacom tablet. I have created `/etc/libwacom/vendor-model.tablet`. `libwacom-list-local-devices` returns the following

```
(libwacom-list-local-devices:20048): libwacom-WARNING **: 21:17:11.478: Vendor Model: Invalid EvdevCode 0x18 for button A, ignoring all codes

devices:
- name: 'Vendor Model'
  bus: 'usb'
  vid: '0xabcd'
  pid: '0x1234'
  nodes: 
  - /dev/input/event18
  - /dev/input/event17
  - /dev/input/event15
  - /dev/input/event14
  - /dev/input/event13
```

The file `vendor-model.tablet` contains

```
[Buttons]
Left=A
EvdevCodes=0x18
```

In reality the button on the tablet is the key e for erase. (I used python evedev to get the code)

I was following the [wacom.example](https://github.com/linuxwacom/libwacom/blob/master/data/wacom.example) file to add the device